# Light, client OS with minimal features such as Firefox only and ICA client

Tags: firefox, linux-distribution

I am looking for a small, lightweight, Linux OS that I can install Firefox and the Citrix ICA client on.  The OS cannot contain any Linux office software, no Thunderbird, no extras.  It needs to be minimal to serve a single purpose, open Firefox which in turns directs to our Netscaler web address, and then let's the user authenticate with their username and password.

[This Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/349069/minimal-gnu-linux-distribution-to-run-only-firefox-and-thunderbird) doesn't suit my needs  Chrome OS is not an option due to the HTML5 Receiver which is embedded.  Our clients prefer (*and we highly recommend*) to use the actual ICA client from Citrix, the Citrix Receiver.

[Thinstation](http://thinstation.github.io/thinstation/) seems to be outdated and has turned out to be more trouble than should be necessary (*seriously, how about a drag and drop option for choosing program repo's and an easy ISO build option*).  Tiny Core Linux (I've already tested), is not suitable either, nor is Puppy Linux.

We would like to be able to repackage this OS into a bootable, and installable ISO (*Thinstation was designed for this purpose, but development seems to have gone to crap*, sorry Donald).

The idea behind this is so that when the desktop loads, Firefox automatically launches in kiosk mode (kiosk mode isn't necessary as long as Firefox auto launches) and the homepage is set to the web address to our Netscaler.

Linux Mint is a nice candidate (as it does what we want, once configured), but it's too robust.  We'd like to avoid spending an hour on the install/setup and there are too many programs that come packaged.  Removing the ability for our users to screw things up on their local machine because they were curious, or "thought they knew" what they were doing, is key.  Simplicity and stability is the primary goal with this.

HP's ThinPro OS, which comes pre-installed on their T510 and T5565 model Thin Clients would also be ideal, but as I've tested on older workstations, it appears HP and Linux designed ThinPro OS for the Thin Client hardware, not the type of CPUs (hardware) used in modern, or older, workstations.

Any ideas or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the Linux Mint, (or another Linux distribution), and customize it by:

- removing the elements that you do not need,
- adding any that you specifically need that are not part of the default and
- setting any default settings

Then generate your own live/installable CD/DVD/USB - full instructions are available online for most Linux Distributions but some specific to Mint can be found [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1784).

Comment: Thanks for the push.  I was leaning towards Mint.  That link you provided may be what I was really missing in this.  I surely appreciate it.  I'll let you know how it goes over the course of the next week as time permits.  Thank you.

Comment: I'll also add that Systemback seems easier to use than the How to customize Linux Mint live cd/dvd guide.